# Reshape dataframe to wide format for GLM analysis

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, format, tapply

I have a 3-column dataframe with plot, species and occurrence data. When I use str() I get the following output:

```
> str(AbundTGLMSOagg)
'data.frame':   1148 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ plot      : Factor w/ 139 levels "H01","H02","H03",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ species   : Factor w/ 62 levels "albleb","albodo",..: 26 42 46 47 48 50 52 53 62 20 ...
 $ occurrence: int  1 1 1 14 1 10 10 1 1 1 ...
```

However, I would like to turn this into a dataframe with 139 obs (= 139 plots) of 62 variables (= 62 species), so that each species is '$ species name' in the str() output.

The str() output should resemble this example here:

```
> str(antTraits$abund)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  41 variables:
 $ Amblyopone.australis         : int  0 0 0 4 2 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Aphaenogaster.longiceps      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Camponotus.cinereus.amperei  : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Camponotus.claripes          : int  2 0 0 1 4 5 6 4 1 2 ...
 $ Camponotus.consobrinus       : int  1 4 6 1 7 11 9 11 19 17 ...
 $ Camponotus.nigriceps         : int  6 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ............ETC
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
> head(antTraits$abund)

  Amblyopone.australis Aphaenogaster.longiceps Camponotus.cinereus.amperei Camponotus.claripes Camponotus.consobrinus Camponotus.nigriceps Camponotus.nigroaeneus
1                    0                       0                           0                   2                      1                    6                      0
2                    0                       0                           0                   0                      4                    0                      1
3                    0                       0                           0                   0                      6                    0                      0
4                    4                       0                           0                   1                      1                    0                      0
5                    2                       0                           0                   4                      7                    0                      0
6                    0                       0                           1                   5                     11                    0                      6
```

This is my dataset: https://pastebin.com/XhArqd5F

```
> foo
     plot albleb albodo antgha apovil artlak briret buclan cansub carsph catspa cropoi dalcul dallan dalnig daloli dilobo dioehr diomal dipint diptub elltom erican
  1:  H01     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
  2:  H02     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
  3:  H03     NA     NA     NA      3     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      3     NA     NA
  4:  H04     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
  5:  H05     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA      1     NA     NA
```

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: What you want to do is called "reshape to wide format". You should be able to find the solution with this search term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using data.table you can do the following

```
    library(data.table)
    dat = setDT(AbundTGLMSOagg)
str(dat)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  8618 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ plot: Factor w/ 139 levels "H01","H02","H03",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ species: Factor w/ 62 levels "albleb","albodo",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ occurrence: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
```

Just dcast your data into wide format:

```
    foo = dcast.data.table(dat, plot ~ species)
str(foo)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  139 obs. of  63 variables:
 $ Var1  : Factor w/ 139 levels "H01","H02","H03",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ albleb: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ albodo: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ antgha: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ apovil: int  0 0 3 0 0 3 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ artlak: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ briret: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Two things. I get NA (not 0) when I run your code for 'foo'. And, I would like the dataframe to exactly resemble the df in the ants example (please see added to question), for 'foo' I get a slightly different output (please see in question also). As such, '$ Var1  : Factor w/ 139 levels "H01","H02","H03",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...' should not be there. Any suggestions to account for these modifications?

Comment: The default for the above function is to return NA's when it does not find an occurrence of plot and a specific species. You can change it by doing `foo[is.na(foo)] = 0`. Var1 corresponds to the plot variable, just rename it or drop it if you don't want it. Else, go to the help page `?dcast.data.table`